# How to migrate anaconda envs to a new directory?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have ssh access to a GPU cluster where I am taking over research from someone else. I wish to take the anaconda envs from /rhome/someoneelse/anaconda3/envs and move them to my installation of anaconda on /rhome/me/anaconda3. I have tried to directly copy the environment to the new directory but that didn't work. What is the way to copy the environment and have my anaconda installation work?

Comment: Do you have access to run `conda` on the other machine?

Comment: It is on the same machine. I can run `conda` in someoneelse/ but I'm unsure if it is running my instance or his instance of conda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `conda-pack`

**Install conda-pack**

```
conda install -c conda-forge conda-pack
```

or

```
pip install conda-pack
```

**Zipping other persons environment**

While in the other machine and **inside the other persons environment** `pack` the environment and save to a tar file:

```
conda pack -n other_persons_environment -o environment_unpacked.tar.gz
```

Transfer the file `environment_unpacked.tar.gz` to your machine using `scp` or another tool.

**Now to unzip the environment**

```
mkdir -p new_directory_for_your_environment

tar -xzf environment_unpacked.tar.gz -C new_directory_for_your_environment
```

**Unpacking**

```
source new_directory_for_your_environment/bin/activate

python

conda-unpack
```

To your comment about running `conda` , you can see which conda is running by this command: `which conda` (to see the path from where `conda` is executing.)

**Note** - I misunderstood the question i.e. I though that the environment was on a different machine. It should be a lot easier if it is on the same machine. You would need to use the same steps with `conda-pack` and just omit the `scp` (other tool) file transfer part.

Comment: Where directory do I run `conda pack -n other_persons_environment -o environment_unpacked.tar.gz
`? I keep getting _CondaPackError: Environment name 'tf-gpu/' doesn't exist_ as an error.

Comment: Can you type in `conda env list` and see if you see the other persons environment in the list? If you don't I'll change my answer.

Comment: Figured it out, first `source activate envToExport` and then use conda-pack.

Comment: @RonYue Thanks, I edited my answer just for clarity :)

Comment: Does conda need to be installed on target machine too?

Comment: @user3731622 yes

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to create .condarc file within your user directory and designate a new `envs_dirs` location.

```
envs_dirs:
  - /path/to/conda_environments
```

After this, you'll have multiple `envs_dirs`, and any new environments created will be automatically saved to `/path/to/conda_environments`.

Once you've set up the .condarc file, rename the environment as follows:

```
conda rename --name env_name new_env_name
```

Since `conda rename` is a combination of `conda create` (at new path) and `conda remove` (at old path), this command will do.

You can then rename back to `env_name` if you want.